# Non-transparent click-through form in .NET

Tags: .net, api, window, transparency

In .NET, is it possible to create a non-transparent form which can be clicked through? I assume there should be some sort of API to transfer mouse clicks to windows right behind the form. Which one?

Comment: WinForms or WPF? (Also this seems like a *very* strange request. A user would typically expect than an opaque window would receive mouse events.)

Comment: How do you propose for the user to figure out what she clicks if the form is non-transparent?

Answer (score 2):

To make a form click-through, you'll need to P/Invoke a few functions from the Windows API and set the form's [extended window styles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff700543.aspx). I've arbitrarily chosen to represent the sample code in VB.NET. If that's not your preference, it's easily converted to C#.

Start with the [`GetWindowLong` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633584.aspx), which you will use to retrieve the extended window styles.

```
Public Const GWL_EXSTYLE As Integer = -20

<DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> _
Public Shared Function GetWindowLong(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, _
                                     ByVal nIndex As Integer) As Integer
End Function
```

You'll also need its sister function, [`SetWindowLong`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633591.aspx), to specify the additional extended window styles.

```
<DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> _
Public Shared Function SetWindowLong(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, _
                                     ByVal nIndex As Integer, _
                                     ByVal dsNewLong As Integer) As Integer
End Function
```

And the constant for the extended window style that will need to be set:

```
Public Const WS_EX_TRANSPARENT As Integer = &H20
```

And now to use all of this, you can override your form's [`OnLoad` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.onload.aspx) and add the following lines:

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnLoad(ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
   ''# Call the base class implementation
   MyBase.OnLoad(e)

   ''# Grab the current extended style information for this form
   Dim initialStyles As Integer = GetWindowLong(Me.Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE)

   ''# Add the transparent extended window style
   Dim newStyles As Integer = initialStyles Or WS_EX_TRANSPARENT

   ''# Update the form's extended window styles
   SetWindowLong(Me.Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE, newStyles)
End Sub
```

Of course, note that it's now going to be impossible for the user to interact with elements on your form and *extremely* difficult for them to close it. Consider carefully whether this is really what you want to do.